# What are context and updater arguments in the React library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I was trying to understand the React through the [React library](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js), but couldn't understand what `context` and `updater` is, which is passed in to the Component.

Following was the code in the library.

```
function Component(props, context, updater) {
  this.props = props;
  this.context = context;
  this.refs = emptyObject;
  // We initialize the default updater but the real one gets injected by the
  // renderer.
  this.updater = updater || ReactNoopUpdateQueue;
}
```

What is the purpose of these things?

Comment: Have you looked at the `ReactNoopUpdateQueue` or any other objects in React's code base that have methods of a similar name?  They might answer some of your questions :-)

Comment: Hi @SeanVieira, Thanks for the help, I couldn't understand from that file too, if you get some time, could you please give brief summary about it? Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

`Context` was introduced to enable developers to pass props to components directly, rather than via the properties of every intermediary component by way of [prop drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling/) (which can become overly cumbersome relatively quickly).

> In some cases, you want to pass data through the component tree without having to pass the props down manually at every level. You can do this directly in React with the powerful “context” API.

---

### Updater

`updater` is an `object` containing `methods` used to update the `DOM`.

This is evident in lines `61` and `79`.

```
// Line 61: Enqueue setState.
this.updater.enqueueSetState(this, partialState, callback, 'setState') 

// Line 79: Force Update.
this.updater.enqueueForceUpdate(this, callback, 'forceUpdate')
```

These `methods` are triggered using [`setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) and [`forceUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) respectively.

Comment: Awesome thank you @ArmanCharan.

Can you please give example for the following case: 

`In some cases, you want to pass data through the component tree 
without having to pass the props down manually at every level. You can do this directly in React with the powerful “context” API.`

Comment: I don't think I could explain it any better than [the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#how-to-use-context). I can defs clarify any questions you might have pertaining to them.