# Difference between ES5 and ES6 constructors in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

In React's source code, the prototype function has a signature with three parameters:

`function Component(props, context, updater) {`

But everytime I see somebody extends `React.Component` using modern ES6 features, they declare constructor with only `props` as follows:

`constructor(props)`

What is the difference between a prototype function and `constructor` literal? And where do the rest two arguments go?

Comment: What is a "*prototype function*"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48106784/what-is-context-and-updater-arguments-in-react-library

Comment: Did you see anyone extend `React.Component` using ES5 syntax, and not also dropping those optional parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obviously use all of the three params provided in the Component. But in general, only in an advanced case we use `props`, not every time. Similarly, you can use others.

Here's an example with [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) api:

**ES6 class component**

```
class ContextConsumer extends React.Component {
  /* 
     contexTypes is a required static property to declare 
     what you want from the context
  */
  static contextTypes = {
      currentUser: React.PropTypes.object
  };
  render() {
    const {currentUser} = this.context;
    return <div>{currentUser.name}</div>;
  }
}
```

**ES6 class component with an overwritten constructor**

```
class ContextConsumer extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = {
      currentUser: React.PropTypes.object
  };
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    ...
  }
  render() {
    const {currentUser} = this.context;
    return <div>{currentUser.name}</div>;
  }
}
```

Example taken from [this blog](https://medium.com/react-ecosystem/how-to-handle-react-context-a7592dfdcbc). I will suggest you to look into the blog to be more familiar with it.

Another param is `updater` which you may have used `this.forceUpdate()` and doing so invoke the updater. But the fact, we do not use `updater` directly in normal case. Though, I have not faced such case to use the updater inside the constructor. You might be able to figure out if you face some advanced case.

---

To be more frank and to use react with clever, I never even try to use `props` as far as possible. They are just provided for us so that we can utilize in lifecycle hooks when needed.

---

Okay, let me explain it a little bit with react code:

```
function Component(props, context, updater) {
  this.props = props;
  this.context = context;
  // If a component has string refs, we will assign a different object later.
  this.refs = emptyObject;
  // We initialize the default updater but the real one gets injected by the
  // renderer.
  this.updater = updater || ReactNoopUpdateQueue;
}

Component.prototype.forceUpdate = function(callback) {
  this.updater.enqueueForceUpdate(this, callback, 'forceUpdate');
};
```

The `Component` function has 3 arguments which is being utilized inside the function. Later, its prototype `forceUpdate` is defined on which the `updater` is being hooked to enqueue the forceUpdate with `enqueueForceUpdate`. So, `this.forceUpdate` actually calling the `Component` updater and allows us to re-render the component. I hope, looking at its prototype method makes sense now.

---

> What is the difference between a prototype function and constructor literal?

As far as I understand, you wanted to know why constructor is being called with the desired params.

The class/function constructor is used so that you can use an override to the function. For eg, passing `props` inside the constructor, you wanted to do an override with this. So, you explicitly notify the function to use the props as used inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

So Es6 added the class keyword along with the constructor for it. It is however just syntactic sugar and is still based on the prototype model as before.
I don't know about the other two argos but I would guess it has to do with the function creating its own lexical scope.